# How to give the path to use my dynamic lib at exec

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I'm facing a problem with my software at execution.
in fact, i try to use a libplugin.so as aditional plugin to my soft but i can't specify the path to find that library.
The problem is that i can't put this lib in /usr/bin/ld because i'm not the sudoer of the computer and i can't be.
When i execute my program , i've got the wrong message : symbol undefined in libxxx.so
when i do " ldd " of my libxxx.so  i see that my aditional libplugin.so is not find.

please help me !

Comment: what OS are you using? Generaly I'd say that extending the path would solve this.

Comment: i'm working on a windows but the exec is on a linux virtually linked

Comment: by extending the path you mean doing export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PATH_TO_LIB/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Comment: Extending LD_LIBRARY_PATH is by many considered a bad idea. What you can do is add this to your linker stage -Wl,--rpath=$PATH_TO_LIB LIB.so. In this way, your executable will look for LIB.so in the location $PATH_TO_LIB

Comment: @JensMunk this is my command now  `LDFLAG = -Wl,--rpath=$/home/usr_camera/views/stage_dev_kalray/Intercepteur/main libprotobuf-lite.so,-export-dynamic,-R -lm -lc -lstdc++ -lpthread -ldl`  But it tells me thaat it doesn't exist , but the LIB.so is here

Comment: The $ should not be there, it used for expanding a variable and the rpath should be a path not the executable main. Try -Wl,--rpath=/home/usr_camera/views/stage_dev_kalray/Intercepteur libprotobuf-lite.so -export-dynamic,-R -lm -lc -lstdc++ -lpthread -ldl